# Unable to sign the jar file properly

Tags: java, jar, applet, signed-applet

I have TViewerApplet.class in com.abc.applet package.To sign the jar file I followed following steps:

1) Created  jar file of com folder using cmd `jar cf Viewer.jar com`

2) Signed jar file using cmd

```
 jarsigner -keystore "C:\Documents and Sett
ings\compstore" -storepass abcdef -keypass abcdef
-signedjar "C:\Documents and Settings\SignedViewer
.jar" "C:\Documents and Settings\Viewer.jar" signFiles
```

Added the below tag in jsp file

`<applet     name="viewerApplet"     id="TViewerApplet"     width="100%"     height="500"     code="com.abc.applet"     align="baseline"     codebase="."     mayscript="mayscript"     archive="SignedViewer.jar,cmbview81.jar"> </applet`>

But the problem is I get

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://10.160.120.221:8086/ICMViewer/com/abc/applet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 9 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.applet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is not that you signed your applet, but rather that it's a misconfiguration of your applet-tag in html.

Comment: You specify the file name of the applet in your code-attribute. Looking at the definition, it seems to me that you only defined the name of the package.